# GWT web.xml - java ee - login and session

Tags: session, gwt, jakarta-ee, authentication, web.xml

I'd like to know if there is a way to provide login support fora all web application content. I mean when user tries to access some site (also static content - html), and he isn't logged or session expires he should be redirected to login site.
Html filter in web.xml for logging is almost what I need, but I also need authentication of html pages.

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>example.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This doesn't work with html pages, only servlet requests.
This should be generic mechanism, not like i.e. writing in every servlet session checking.
Thanks for all resopnes.

Comment: This should work as well with HTML pages served by the same webapp. Your problem is caused somewhere else. Probably they are served by a different webapp/server? Or you are not running the filter code or mapping which you think you're running?

Answer (score 0):

There are standard web.xml configuration options for defining this.
You shouldn't have to define a custom filter.

See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B31017_01/web.1013/b28967/adding_security003.htm

> If your application contains pages that require a user to be authenticated against a data store in order to be accessed, you must declare the following in the web.xml configuration file:
>
> <security-role> defines valid roles in the security context.
>
> <login-config> defines the protocol for authentication, for example form-based or HTTPS.
>
> <security-constraint> defines the resources specified by URL patterns and HTTP methods that can be accessed only by authorized users or roles.
>
> <servlet> defines the servlet that provides authentication.
>
> <servlet-mapping> maps the servlet to a URL pattern.
>
> defines the filter used to transform the content of the authentication request.
>
> <filter-mapping> maps the filter to the file extensions used by the application. For details about the ADF binding filter, see Configuring the ADF Binding Filter.